# Parsing error in blacklist-framebuffer.conf occurring at boot

Tags: boot, blacklist

So a while ago I had an issue with the Radeon proprietary driver after a ubuntu-base update. Long story short, it stopped working and after quite a struggle with it, which involved installing XFCE along with unity, I decided to stick with the Intel Sandybridge Mobile driver. Problem is, now everytime I boot I get the error:

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:686 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf line 6: ignoring bad line starting with 'fb'
```

Is there a safe fix for this? Can I just comment it out/set it to false?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by changing line 6, which was just
    fb

to

```
blacklist radeonfb
```

I then updated the initial ramdisk filesystem with

```
sudo update-initramfs -k all -c
```

and reboooted. It seems to do the trick